# Checkpoint VPN-1 R60 and Windows 7 64 Bit Client

Tags: windows-7, vpn, checkpoint

As per my knowledge of checkpoint VPN-1. My company is using checkpoint VPN-1 R 60 ( I guess as I dont know how to check server version) Firewall(VPN Server). Now the problem is that I installed Windows 7 64 bit. But, after my research I found that there are not even one client (SecuRemote/SecuClient) for Win7 64 bit, when Firewall or server is R60. I thought of some open source solutions. Can you guys please suggest me some with the configuration required.

As of now, I know the IP of the server. I know my username and password using which I connect and that is not my domain password. that i can confirm to you guys.

I am not a network guy. I am more of a developer. But, I need some help in this.So, let me know if I can provide you more details.

Please please i need urgent help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance your company can patch up to R70, so you can use the [win7 client](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk36681)?  I think it's fairly safe at this point to say that Win7 will be around for a while.  (if they're currently paying for support, the download should be free and "relatively" painless - I was never fond of letting my firewall OS fall very far behind the current version, kind of defeats the purpose)

Comment: I am sorry but,I am not the sysadmin of my comp. I am trying to install windows 7 on one of the company laptop. So, there is no way that I can push them to upgrade to R70. So, there is no way to use VPN with windows 7 64 bit and R60

Comment: Ouch, best of luck!  I'm not certain this is possible.  Though I've seen lower-version clients connect to higher server versions before.  It might be worth a shot to install the R70 and see if it connects.  Perhaps your IT hasn't rolled out the new client versions yet.